# Visual Studio 2010 including old version of jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I create a new ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2010, it creates the scripts directory, like it should, however the version of JQuery it sticks under the scripts directory is an old version of JQuery. Version 1.36 I believe. How can I update this so that Visual Studio 2010 will include the newest version of jquery? I know I can remove it and manually add it, but I don't want to have to do this everytime I create a new project.

Comment: I believe VS 2010 shipped with jQuery 1.4.1

Comment: Yes you are right. There is a version 1.4.2 now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\Web\CSharp\1033
```

(obviously, adjusting the path to your local PC if needed, and there is a separate folder for VB there as well)

Every .zip file is a project template. Update as needed.